# Intel MKL Warning on Jupyter Notebook (Python)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, intel, intel-mkl

This is my first time posting, so I apologize if I am missing anything that is common practice.

For the last month or so, whenever I import anything on Jupyter Notebook, I have been getting warnings that look like this:

*Intel MKL WARNING: Support of Intel(R) Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2 (Intel(R) SSE4.2) enabled only processors has been deprecated. Intel oneAPI Math Kernel Library 2025.0 will require Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions (Intel(R) AVX) instructions.*

These usually occur when importing libraries such as NumPy and Matplotlib. It's also occurring when running a linear regression using StatsModels:

```
weight_model = smf.ols('Weight ~ Day', weight).fit()
intercept = weight_model.params['Intercept']
coefficient = weight_model.params['Day']

print(weight_model.params)
```

This is odd to me because I do not have an Intel processor, I have a Mac M1. Is there any way to make them stop occurring?

Thank you for the help!

```
!export MKL_ENABLE_INSTRUCTIONS=SSE4_2
```

This did not work.

Comment: Is this relevent - https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/13236 - in particular see the comment on using osx-arm64 version for M1/M2 (https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/13236#issuecomment-1657243903)

Comment: PS MKL is a low level "Math Kernel Library" usually very optimised for specific hardware. So no supprised you see these messages when using math-centric python libraries that use it in the background, or that you'd see warnings if you have a version optimised for the wrong platform installed.

Comment: Rosetta 2 emulates an x86-64 with only SSE4.2 and earlier, not AVX.  Unless that changes (perhaps on future Apple CPUs that support 256-bit vectors with AArch64 SVE, their equivalent of AVX / AVX-512), you won't be able to use MKL from oneAPI 2025.0 when it comes out, which it's warning you about ahead of time.  Use native AArch64 Python / NumPy instead of x86-64 with Intel libraries unless there's some specific reason.